# EF Navigation Property in Database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database and I want to know how to map the relationships via code.  I'm not sure if I understand exactly how this works.

Suppose I have two classes:

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressID {get;set;}
    public String Street {get;set;}
}

public class Shipment
{
    [Key]
    public int ShipmentID {get;set;}
    public int ShipToAddressID {get;set;}

    public virtual Address ShipToAddress {get;set;}
}
```

I have a few questions:
Does the navigation property merely give me access to the dbset of Address?
It seems that is not the case.  However, if not, how do I specify which property is the foreign key on which the relationship exists? eg: How do I tell this navigation property that it should match the Address entities based on the AddressID property ?

Again, I'm doing this all via code.  So I'm mapping the properties in the OnModelCreating call in the context.  So please make suggestions/provide answers with that in mind.

Comment: You can look at fluent mappings https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx

Comment: I answered the question, but in Database First, you might as well use the POCO code generation rather than handcoding any fluent mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in need of the HasRequired, WithMany, and HasForeignKey configuration methods.

```
EntityTypeConfiguration<Shipment> config = modelBuilder.Entity<Shipment>();

config
   .HasRequired(s=>s.ShipToAddress)
   .WithMany()
   .HasForeignKey(s=>s.ShipToAddressID)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I searched all over and couldn't find anything like the "HasForeignKey" method.  So, by specifying the .WithMany() option, does that say that the Address entity must also have a navigation property to the shipment?

Comment: It means that any single `Address` entity could refer to many `Shipment`s.  (which makes sense).  Additionally, we have not specified a navigation property within `Address`.  You need the `HasForeignKey` configuration method because your navigation property is /not/ named `AddressId`.  Some additional light reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToOptional